# Encryption program, "string index out of range"

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer, and I have encountered a problem that I cannot solve. I am creating a program that encrypts text by adding the ordinal values of each letter in turn with the ordinal values of each letter in the text, and prints the new characters using the chr() function.

```
codeword = input('Enter codeword : ')
encrypt = input('Enter text to encrypt : ')
j = 0
for i in encrypt:
    check = (ord(encrypt[j])+ ord(codeword[j])-96)
    if check > 122:
        no = check - 26
        ok = (chr(no))
        ok = ok.replace("%", " ")
        print(ok, end="")
    if check < 122:
        yes = (chr(check))
        yes = yes.replace("%", " ")
        print(yes, end="")
    j+=1
```

When I choose abc as the codeword and hey as the word to encrypt, it works fine and prints igb. However, if i choose abc as the codeword and hello world as the word to encrypt, i recieve the following message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/task 2.py", line 9, in <module>
    check = (ord(encrypt[j])+ ord(codeword[j])-96)
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: oh, I put a slightly different code up i the question, but even stil, it only cycles through the letters in the word to encrypt tup until it runs out of letters in the codeword

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions-- that's not allowed on the site, among other reasons because it wastes the effort of the people who took time to answer your question in the hopes it would help both you and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `encrypt` is longer than `codeword`, you can reach, say, index `5`.  `encrypt[5]` is , but `codeword[5]` doesn't exist.  You need to find the shortest one:

```
for e, c in zip(encrypt, codeword):
    check = (ord(e) + ord(c) - 96)
    ...
```

You could also use the `min()` function:

```
for j in range(min(len(encrypt), len(codeword))):
    ...
```

**Edit**: It appears that you wish to cycle.  You can use `itertools` for that task:

```
from itertools import cycle

for e, c in zip(encrypt, cycle(codeword)):
    ...
```

`cycle()` will keep iterating through an object forever.  When it reaches the end, it moves back to the beginning.  For example:

```
for char in cycle("here"):
    print(char)

h
e
r
e
h
e
r
e
h
...
```

Since `zip()` goes only so far as the shortest iterable, it will cycle only as far as the length of `encrypt`.  For example:

```
for e, c in zip("this sentence", cycle("abc")):
    print(e, c)

t a
h b
i c
s a
  b
s c
e a
n b
t c
e a
n b
c c
e a
```

It still works if `encrypt` is shorter than `codeword`:

```
for e, c in zip("hi", cycle("abc")):
    print(e, c)

h a
i b
```

**Edit 2**: It appears that you want to keep spaces as spaces.  You can do that like this:

```
for e, c in zip(encrypt, cycle(codeword)):
    if e == " ":
        check = ord(e)
    else:
        check = (ord(e) + ord(c) - 96)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, however, it still only prints up until the codeword letters run out.

Comment: thank you so much, however, I dont really understand why this works, would you be able to explain it to me?

Comment: There is still one minor problem... When there is a space between two words in the text to encrypt against, it turns into a symbol!                                                                    Enter codeword : hello
Enter text to encrypt : hello my name is                                                                                                      pjxxd(rk,cirq,xa

Comment: @D.C: Add a check: `if e.strip(): check = (ord(e) ... else: check = ord(e)`

Comment: i dont really understandthis